# ReactJS and Socket.io : state is reseted to initial value after receiving a new message from websocket server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, socket.io, state

im creating a simple chat application using reactJS and socket.io for webSocket,but when i got a new message from server to add it to the message array state, is reseted to initial value which is an empty Array :

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";

let socket;

export default () => {
  const [messages,setMessages]=useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket = socketIOClient("https://localhost:5000");;
    
    socket.on("resp-chat-user",  data => {
        setMessages([{
            message:data.message,
          }]);;
    })
    return () => socket.close();  
  }, []);


  const SendMessage=(msg)=>{
    if(msg && msg!="")
    {
      socket.emit("req-chat-user", {
        message:msg,
        to: SOCKET_ID
      });
      setMessages([...messages,{
        message:msg
      }])
    }
  }

  return (
      <>
    <ul>
        {messages.map(msg=>(
            <li>{msg}</li>
        ))}
    </ul>
    <button type="submit" onClick={()=>SendMessage("HOLA")}>send</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

the way that i update state inside socket listener is wrong, i should use :

```
   setMessages(messages => [ ...messages, {
      type:"other",
      message:data.message,
    } ]);
```

insead of

```
  setMessages([ ...messages, {
      type:"other",
      message:data.message,
    } ]);
```